# Cannot create a ManyToMany relationship between two entites

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, entity-relationship

As I referenced in the title I have two entities in google app engine project. The first one is "store" and the other is "product". Before adding the ManyToMany annotation the entities stored regularly but after the relationship addition the entities cannot be stored even though there is a successful message returned!!

Here are the entities:

**Store.java**

```
package com.cheapchase.server;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name="store", catalog="content", uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STORE_NAME"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STORE_CODE")})
public class Store{

    private int storeCode;
    private Date dueDate;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String storeName;
    private String storeAddress;
    private String storeDescription;
    private String userId;
    private Long id;
    private Set<Product> product;

    public Store(){

    }

    public Store(String storeName, int storeCode){
        this.storeName = storeName;
        this.setStoreCode(storeCode);
    }

    public Store(String storeName, int storeCode, Set<Product> product){
        this.storeName = storeName;
        this.storeCode = storeCode;
        this.product = product;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STORE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="STORE_NAME", nullable=false)
    public String getStoreName() {
        return this.storeName;
    }

    public void setStoreName(String storeName) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }

    /*
     * Define the Many To Many relationship with product
     */
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "storae_product", catalog = "content", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "STORE_ID", nullable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false)})
    public Set<Product> getProduct(){
        return this.product;
    }
    public void setProduct(Set<Product> product){
        this.product = product;
    }

    /*
     * Define the rest getters and setters
     */
    public Date getDueDate() {
        return dueDate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return this.emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getStoreDescription() {
        return storeDescription;
    }

    public void setStoreDescription(String storeDescription) {
        this.storeDescription = storeDescription;
    }

    public String getStoreAddress() {
        return storeAddress;
    }

    public void setStoreAddress(String storeAddress) {
        this.storeAddress = storeAddress;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getStoreCode() {
        return storeCode;
    }

    public void setStoreCode(int storeCode) {
        this.storeCode = storeCode;
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Store [dueDate=");
        builder.append(dueDate);
        builder.append(", name=");
        builder.append(storeName);
        builder.append(", description=");
        builder.append(storeDescription);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();

    }

}
```

**Product.java**

```
package com.cheapchase.server;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Column;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product", catalog = "content")
public class Product {

    private Long productId;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int barCode;
    Blob image;
    private Set<Store> stores = new HashSet<Store>(0);

    public Product(){

    }
    public Product(String name, String description){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Product(String name, String description, Set<Store> stores){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.stores = stores;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getProductId(){
        return this.productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Long productId){
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
    public Set<Store> getStore(){
        return this.stores;
    }

    public void setStore(Set<Store> store){
        this.stores = store;
    }

    public int getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }

    public void setBarCode(int barCode) {
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your Store.java references a "storae_product" table, which appears to be a typo.  Did you mean "store_product"?

Comment: Nice notice but it was mistyping in the submission of the question not in the source code.